# Bash heartbeat script for remote machines

Tags: bash, osx-mavericks

I'm looking for critiques or other/better ideas on this script. I have multiple remote machines that perform various function via ssh and rsync to a server in a data center. I though one way to do a check on them was for each one to touch a file on the server. I have a text file (check-ins.txt) that has the machines listed (the touched files). This script reads the text file, and compares the mod time to current time on the touched files, and if it's over x, or doesn't exist, send me an email.

```
siteDIR="some/path"

while read -r line; do
if [ -e $sitesDIR$line ] ; then
    echo "$line exists"
    time1="$(( $(date +%s) - $(stat -f%c $sitesDIR$line) ))"
    if [ $time1 -lt 3600 ] ; then
        echo "we're good"
    else
        echo "we're NOT good - over 1 hour old - send an email"
    fi
else
    echo "something is up with the config file- $line doesn't exist - send an email"
fi
done < check-ins.txt
```

I'm getting better at bash, but not a pro yet. Any constructive criticism/or better ideas would be appreciated. Heck, I just learned about "source" and "at". Having fun.... thanks

Comment: SO is for specific problems that need to be solved. To ask for code review, criticism, suggestions, etc. there is a separate site: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @AndrewMedico - I didn't know "code review" existed, now I do - thanks

Comment: This question belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not a bad script.  A few things

Since you want to monitor that these hosts are okay, you want to make sure your monitor is valid.  You mentioned that the remote hosts do various things using ssh and rsync.  So for the check in, you want these hosts to some how "check in" using ssh and rsync.  Does that make sense?

So you would want one monitor to be working to let you know if the remote host can ssh to the server

You would want a second monitor to be working to let you know remote host can rsync to the server

So in this case, you can have the first file, perhaps named "ssh.txt" put there by the client using ssh command (like ssh hostname "touch filename")

Create a second file, perhaps named "rsync.txt", put there by the client using rsync command (locally, do a touch, than rsync it over to the server)

Then your monitor above can monitor both files

I haven't used that syntax before

```
time1="$(( $(date +%s) - $(stat -f%c $sitesDIR$line) ))"
```

So I don't know if it's correct.

Okay, next thought, just how I would do it, maybe give you some food for thought.  That might potentially be a lot of emails you are generating.  I'm guessing your script runs once an hour?  I would adjust so that it would only send me one email, maybe two emails

I would first create my check in files with a hostname, e.g. host1.ssh.txt, host1.rsync.txt)

First email: all hosts that have not checked in (no ssh.txt or rsync.txt file exists)

Second email: all hosts that have checked in but not in the last hour

In the first email, use your check-ins.txt as input and do an "ls" on all the files.  Any file that doesn't exist, add it to an output file like "does-not-exist.txt" and then send the contents of that file in your first email

Then I would likely do some sort of find command for files older than an hour, and then put a list of those files in a second file like "older-than-an-hour.txt".  Remember the hostname is already in the file so when you read an email and see something like

```
host1.ssh.txt
host2.ssh.txt
host2.rsync.txt
```

etc.. 
You can tell what hosts and what methods are failing their monitors

Just some ideas!

Comment: Oh, and another idea is to look into some monitoring tool like Big Brother (old, free, still works!  Have actually had more issues with the commercial version than the free version!)

Comment: in your first paragraph, I do exactly that using ssh....

Comment: Good man.  :)  Hope the rest of the ideas are thought provoking

Comment: in your first paragraph, I do exactly that using ssh....
    ssh $user@$peer touch /myDirectory/check-ins/sites/$cust_name
and that creates the file I'm checking the time against. I'll assume rsync is working if ssh is working because I rsync using ssh. The syntax is correct (assuming it's correct if it works!). If they are checking in regularly, I don't want to know, as the emails would be many. Thanks for the input! btw, I use Nagios to monitor all internal servers. Since the remote one is kind of out of our control (no public ip), it would probably be more difficult, no?